# how to check if serialized data has an index in php

Tags: php, serialization

I have two serialized data one has notification_color and one does not , i want to perform a check in mysql data if serialized string does not has notification_color index than add that

First :-

```
a:4:{s:11:"header_dark";s:7:"#2185C5";s:12:"header_light";s:7:"#7ecefd";s:10:"text_color";s:7:"#ffffff";s:9:"text_dark";s:7:"#000000";}
```

Second:-

```
a:5:{s:11:"header_dark";s:7:"#333E4B";s:12:"header_light";s:7:"#f05a28";s:10:"text_color";s:7:"#ffffff";s:9:"text_dark";s:7:"#ffffff";s:18:"notification_color";s:7:"#ff0000";}
```

Comment: ok i have solve this , first unserialized string then adding required index and value than serialized array to string  again will put code here

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as answer and then accept it?

Comment: yes putting in short while , thanks